# Code is picking link text, not the href

Tags: jquery

I am trying to copy `href` to clipboard using `zeroclipboard`.

This code is picking link text, not the href.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#content li a').zclip({
path:'http://www.steamdev.com/zclip/js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
copy:$('#content li a').text()
});
})
```

Any help please?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using `copy: this.href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.attr()`

```
$('#content li a').attr('href')
```

Use `.attr('key')` to get the value of that attribute.

You can also use `.prop()`.

`.text()` gives you the text of the selected element

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [**attr()**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) or [**prop()**](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to get the **href** value.

do like this:

```
$('#content li a').attr("href");
```

or:

```
$('#content li a').prop("href");
```

[**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/) returns the text between the opening and closing tag of the element.